# FMX - GPS location provider requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Tags: android, delphi, gps, firemonkey

How add in project permission for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION?

When call below code my app stop working and get message ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

```
LIntent := TJIntent.Create;   LIntent.setClassName(TAndroidHelper.Activity.getBaseContext,TAndroidHelper.StringToJString('com.embarcadero.services.RServiceAndroid'));
TAndroidHelper.Activity.startService(LIntent);
```

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Android_Permission_Model and http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Uses_Permissions